# getting data attrib value from html to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

So I have a bunch of images for which I am adding a few data attributes, which I want to use later on in jquery.

The PHP/HTML looks kind of like this:

```
<? 
foreach($images as $image) 
{
?>
<div class='dyn-img'>
  <img <!-- start image tag -->
      src="<? echo $image['src']?>"
      data-aspect-ratio ="<? echo $image['aspect_ratio']?>"
      ... //other dynamic data attribs
  > <!-- end image tag -->
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Later on in jQuery, I need to take these dynamically loaded images and pass their aspect ratios into a library function:

So in the jQuery part I do (inside document.ready fn):

```
$(".img-holder > img").cropper({
  aspectRatio: 1, //<-- this needs to be the data-aspect-ratio defined earlier
  ... other attributes...
});
```

I tried using `aspectRatio: this.data("aspect-ratio")` however that gives me a javascript error saying

```
TypeError: this.data is not a function
aspectRatio: this.data("aspect-ratio"),
```

My jQuery skills are basic, so I am hoping there is some jQuery/Javascript masters here who can help show me how I can pass that value into this function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would loop using `each`, get the attribute, then call `cropper`

```
$(".img-holder > img").each(function() {
    var size = $(this).data("aspect-ratio");
    $(this).cropper({
        aspectRatio: size
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Basically I guess where I was going wrong was using `this.data()` instead of `$(this).data()`